# Apple Store publish app as a guest member role

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

i start working for a big company as ios developer and in the next weeks i need to publish a very simple app. Now for now the company do not set me as Admin Role in his iTunes Connect Company Developer account.

Please what is the best and professional way to do this?
Who have to prepare the certificate? I can not do it if the set me as Member role.
Please see here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

(NB: for now i test the app with my own ios dev certificate).

Comment: Hi Maddy, i have a ios dev individual account and the company a ios dev company account.
If they invite me - what the role correct role for me for build p12 + mprov certifications and create/send to review an app?
What is the correct workflow? I'm an young ios dev!
Mary :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm set as Admin Role on the organization I work for and can do everything needed to successfully publish an app to the App Store.

Comment: Sorry David, i can not set me ad admin role!

Comment: Sorry David, i can not set me ad admin role! How to do? I can create my own p12 dev certificate and ask to the company to send me the other to build the app? Please very very help!

Comment: In this case, I think the best way would be to send the project to them and then they would build and publish it.